# Nice buttons like these in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I am trying to make nice looking user input buttons for my app. Just like the ones shown in the screenshot below. I looked into IBAForms but that project is not only super complicated to incorporate in your app but also it has complier issues left and right with Xcode 4.2. So I gave up on that idea.

If I want to use just Xcode 4.2 built in technology, how can I achieve these kinds of buttons relatively easily? meaning

How can I create a button with Text and user selected values as shown in this screenshot? I am sure there are multiple ways of going about it.

[image]

Comment: It appears to just be a table view, have you looked into that?

Comment: What buttons? these are just tableview cells as most people have said already.look into what @jrturton is saying. These look like static cells which were made available in Xcode 4.2's storyboards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is as follows. You don't need any external libraries.

- Create a new application using storyboards
- Add a table view controller
- Set the type to "static content"
- Set the number of sections you want in the inspector - a section is a group of cells that are grouped together. Your example has 5 sections visible.
- Drag in some cells - play around with the types to see what you get, for example the first one is a default type with a "detail disclosure button" accessory view, the second groups are "detail right" (or similar) stype with a disclosure accessory view.

Done!

Answer (score 6):

That's a grouped `UITableView` with multiple sections. It seems that you're probably new to iOS development. I recommend that you take a look at the [`UITableView` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I have been developing iOS apps for couple of months now. I have done/created quite a few tableviews but this is more complicated.

Comment: It's really not. That is 1 table view with 5 sections.

Comment: To add to Mark's answer, the table cells are styled as UITableViewCellStyleValue1 cells.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html  with a UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator (the ">")

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that there isn't a way to do this "easily" with just the standard `UITableView` APIs. I would recommend checking out [QuickDialog](https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog) and see if that suits your needs.